# Creating non blocking pipes to child that does not block and can be reused

Tags: c++, pipe, exec, fork

I am trying to create a inter process communication bus using pipes.
I can send messages to the client, and i can receive messages at the client.

I also tried to create another pipe which goes the other way, child-> parent.

However I need this communication to be non blocking and I want to send messages in both directions with some undefined time gap in between.

It appears i can not send more then one message, I take it it is due to the `fclose();` closing the stream, however if i remove the close, the program stops working...

How can I make this code nonblocking two way parent -> child communication through pipes?

Later I want to connect a child-binary using exec(), and connecting this binary's stdin, stdout to my parent, so that I can pass messages to the stdin of the child and retrieve answers through the "childParent" descriptor.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define READ_SIDE 0
#define WRITE_SIDE 1

  /* Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */


  void
  read_from_pipe (int file)
  {
    FILE *stream;
    int c;
    stream = fdopen (file, "r");
    while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
      putchar (c);
    fclose (stream);
  }

  /* Write some random text to the pipe. */

  void
write_to_pipe (int file, char * message)
  {
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen (file, "w");
    fprintf (stream, message);
    //fprintf (stream, "goodbye, world!\n");

    //Dont forget to close
    fclose (stream);
  }

void end(){
  //kill process and close pipes

}



  int
  main (void)
  {
    pid_t pid;
    int parentToChild[2];
    int childToParent[2];

    /* Create the pipes. */
    if (pipe (parentToChild))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pipe (childToParent))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /* Create the child process. */
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
    {
      /* This is the child process.
       Close other end first. */
      close(childToParent[READ_SIDE]);
      close (parentToChild[WRITE_SIDE]);
      read_from_pipe (parentToChild[READ_SIDE]);
      write_to_pipe(childToParent[WRITE_SIDE], "Child sent message to parent");
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
    {
      /* The fork failed. */
      fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
      /* This is the parent process.
       Close other end first. */
      close(childToParent[WRITE_SIDE]);
      close (parentToChild[READ_SIDE]);
      write_to_pipe (parentToChild[WRITE_SIDE],"Parent sent message to child");
      read_from_pipe(childToParent[READ_SIDE]);
      //Send more messages...

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
It appears that sometimes the communication only happens one way, depending on which process gets to read/write first I guess.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html#Creating-a-Pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues to be considered.  First, pipes have a finite
maximum length (4096 was common in the distant past); any write to a
pipe which has more data in it than that will block, as will any read
from an empty pipe.  These are fundamental to the way pipes work, so
when you speak of non-blocking, you have to take them into consideration
(or use asynchronous IO).

Second, if you really need to control things at this level, you might
want to consider using Posix level IO, rather than streams.  If you do
use streams (either iostream or `FILE*`), then you have to take into
account the buffering they use.  In particular, when you want to be sure
that the data is output to the pipe, you need to flush (`fflush` on
the `FILE*`).  With regards to sending more than one message, and the
code not working without the `fclose`, replacing the `fclose` with
`fflush` should be all you need to fix this.

And while I'm at it: your use of `fprintf` for output is extremely
dangerous.  If you're getting a message from an external source, and
(possibly) don't know what it contains, you should use `fputs` to output
it, or possibly something like `fprintf( fd, "%s\n", message )` (if you
want to append a new line).  As you've done it, if the message contains
a `'%'`, strange things will happen.  More generally, you should prefer
the much safer iostream, but for simple things like this, it doesn't
matter much.  And for what you're actually doing, Posix level IO is
probably just as appropriate, or more so.  With Posix level IO, you
don't get any formatting or buffering: but since you're not using the
formatting capabilities, and the buffering it part of your problem...

Comment: Flush seems to work, now i have one way communication working... that is a start... (Do I need to extract the stream object from read and write and call close it somewhere to not risk running out of streams?)

Comment: @DavidKarlsson At some point, you'll have to close the streams; probably when a thread terminates.  (You'll have to close both sides at that point: the thread should close the streams it uses, and the parent process may close the corresponding streams on its side when it sees EOF on its receiving stream, or it may want to join first, and then close.)

Comment: Can you point me in any direction conserning the POSIX IO, I need to be able to connect stdin and stdout of a child process as mentioned above. Ideally the solution can be used on both OSX and Windows without to many changes, I realize that may be much to wish for though...

Comment: In your case, Posix IO means just dropping the `fdopen`, and using `read`, `write` and `close` instead of the stream functions you're using.

Comment: Thank you, I found a good read example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863308/read-write-through-a-pipe-in-c