# Incomplete messages in pipe connected to stdout of child process

Tags: c++, pipe, posix, readfile

I have a parent and a child process in my application.

The parent is scheduled to peek the pipe every X ms and then read the pipe if it has any content. The content is basically used in RPC's, meaning the parent does not much more than passing the message on to another type of IPC.

This seems to work, the child produce output with very close to 100ms delay, and the Remote procedures get called.

**Sometimes however it seems that the parent process gets a incomplete message, as if the child is writing at the same time as the parent is trying to read. This occurs a couple of times every minute.
Is this expected?**

I know that all messages end with a specific character '}', I am sending JSON. Should I peek and make sure I have this character before reading. (I have not done it already since doing so would change the architecture of the parent from an dumb-messaging-gateway, to one with "message inspection").

I am using Posix `write()` and `read()`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863308/read-write-through-a-pipe-in-c). With `O_NONBLOCK` set like [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/read.html).

I have made the pipe nonblocking since I get data continuously from the child and I cant have it block my main application.

If I need to implement inspection of the message content, I might as well It is possible that I get more than one message as well implement handling for multiple messages at the same read(), maybe I can split the received message on '}' and pass each message on for handling.

Comment: Reads may be short for a variety of reasons. It is more reliable to have the client announce to the parent how many bytes the message will be before sending the message, and the parent reads the length first, and then reads that many bytes.

Comment: The sleeps and the peeks are pointless. Just block in the read call. Then you'll always block for the correct length of time.

Answer (score 2):

A pipe is a stream of characters, not a stream of messages.   There is no guarantee that the pipeline will preserve your message boundaries, so it is the reader's responsibility to reassemble a complete message.

This can be done by looking for end-of-message characters (a new line character is often used for text data; an EOT (0x04) or ETX (0x03) character is often used for binary data.)

Messages boundaries may also be communicated by sending a header containing a count before each message.

Comment: Is there any way I can peek the message without destroying it, so that I can check for new line characters. and read if a newline is found?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't, but even if you can, it would probably be better to repeatedly accumulate "whatever is available" in your listener in a buffer, and only act on a message when you've got the whole thing (i.e. you've received the trailing `}` [possibly counting opening/closing braces depending on the complexity of your JSON).